# Creating Views dynamically in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I know how to create views in MVC.

But I am searching for the idea to dynamically add a create type view for which I will pass the scafolding Model as parameter to the controller method. I cannot go manually but I want to add view during some controller action.

I want to have a code something look like...

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public void SomeAction(string modelName)
    {
        //add view of create type 
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to clarify your question a little? I'm not sure if it's entirely clear. Are you hoping to create new Views (files) with this? I.e. the user submits code which is then used as the code for a new view? Is security a concern here?

Comment: @RowanFreeman All I want to do is to add a view programmatically by passing a 'modelName' as argument to a controller action.

Comment: Can you just do `return View(modelName)`?

Comment: No, Rowan Freeman . I do not have a view yet but just want to create now programmatically.

Comment: So, as I asked in my first comment, are you wanting to create a new file? `modelName.cshtml`?

Comment: Exactly, that way Sir.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check out [RazorEngine](https://razorengine.codeplex.com/) that will give you greater control to build robust templates. Based on "Create Type", you can select specific view and pass model object to the view. The result of `Parse` method will be plain html.

```
  string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
  string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

If you want to achieve something for which [RazorEngine](https://razorengine.codeplex.com/) is of no help, please clarify your requirement a bit more.

Comment: I tried doing this using Razor nuGet package but I end up with the  problem of 'Could not load file or assembly 'RazorEngine, Version=3.4.1.0...'. I checked .NET 4.5.1 is installed in my machine.

Comment: Did you installed it using "Install-Package RazorEngine"? Were it installed successfully? I did just now, it was giving an error then I removed "dependentAssembly" section for "System.Web.Razor" from web.config. It all worked then.

Comment: After successful installation of RazorEngine, I cannot find such a code in web.config. i.e. I cannot get "dependentAssembly" section for "System.Web.Razor". I am using Visual Studio 2013 ultimate edition.